# How can I perform word tokenization of a text, using the tokenize annotator, with pycorenlp (Python wrapper for Stanford CoreNLP), without ssplit?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, tokenize

I am trying to run [pycorenlp](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp), which is a Python wrapper for [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/), to perform word tokenization of a text, using the [`tokenize`](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html#description) annotator.

I first launch a Stanford CoreNLP:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 50000
```

then run:

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

text_input = 'this is a test.'
print('text_input: {0}'.format(text_input))
text_output = nlp.annotate(text_input, properties={
                    'annotators': 'tokenize',
                    'outputFormat': 'json'
                })
print('text_output: {0}'.format(text_output))
```

Surprisingly, this gives no output:

```
text_input: this is a test.
text_output: {}
```

Why?

---

If I add the [`ssplit`](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ssplit.html), then `text_output` isn't empty anymore:

```
text_input = 'this is a test.'
print('text_input: {0}'.format(text_input))
text_output = nlp.annotate(text_input, properties={
                    'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit',
                    'outputFormat': 'json'
                })
print('text_output: {0}'.format(text_output))
```

outputs:

```
text_input: this is a test.
text_output: {u'sentences': [{u'parse': u'SENTENCE_SKIPPED_OR_UNPARSABLE', u'index': 0, u'tokens': [{u'index': 1, u'word': u'this', u'after': u' ', u'characterOffsetEnd': 4, u'characterOffsetBegin': 0, u'originalText': u'this', u'before': u''}, {u'index': 2, u'word': u'is', u'after': u' ', u'characterOffsetEnd': 7, u'characterOffsetBegin': 5, u'originalText': u'is', u'before': u' '}, {u'index': 3, u'word': u'a', u'after': u' ', u'characterOffsetEnd': 9, u'characterOffsetBegin': 8, u'originalText': u'a', u'before': u' '}, {u'index': 4, u'word': u'test', u'after': u'', u'characterOffsetEnd': 14, u'characterOffsetBegin': 10, u'originalText': u'test', u'before': u' '}, {u'index': 5, u'word': u'.', u'after': u'', u'characterOffsetEnd': 15, u'characterOffsetBegin': 14, u'originalText': u'.', u'before': u''}]}]}
```

Can't I use the [`tokenize`](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html#description) annotator without having to use the [`ssplit`](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ssplit.html) annotator?

The  [overview of the annotator dependencies](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/dependencies.html) seems to say I should be able to use the [`tokenize`](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html#description) annotator alone:

[image]

Comment: I crossposted the question on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-perform-word-tokenization-of-a-text-using-the-tokenize-annotator-with-pycorenlp-Python-wrapper-for-Stanford-CoreNLP-without-ssplit

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the API doesn't seem to be responding if the only annotator provided is 'tokenize'. It should be have defaulted to `PTBTokenizer` as mentioned in the docs.  Another relevant question is present here: [Stanford CoreNLP gives NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21742186/1005215) . However, if you only want to tokenize and do nothing else, you can do:

```
nwani@ip-172-31-43-96:~/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09$ ~/jre1.8.0_101/bin/java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer <<< "this is a test"
this
is
a
test
PTBTokenizer tokenized 4 tokens at 19.11 tokens per second.
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to tokenize only, using pycorenlp?